# Mac wireless keyboard doesn't work in GRUB 2

Tags: boot, wireless, grub2, keyboard, mac

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now I cant boot into Mac OSX anymore. I am using the standard wireless keyboard that all Apple computers come with and it doesnt work at all in the grub 2 menu when booting up and automatically boots Ubuntu after 10 seconds. is there any way of using a wireless keyboard for this? and if not, is there a way to remove ubuntu while running it?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have USB Legacy Support enabled in the BIOS (also check for other USB/keyboard related settings)

If that doesn't help: Does it work with other bootloaders? With other wireless/non-wireless keyboards?