# MacBook trackpad and keyboard won't work

Tags: keyboard, mouse, hardware, macbook

I have a MacBook (early 2016 model) trackpad and keyboard. I am trying to install Ubuntu on my MacBook. My keyboard works in GRUB (with arrow keys and stuff) but not when Ubuntu boots.

This has happened on Ubuntu 16.10 and Linux Mint 18.1 I believe.

I've tried adding GRUB parameters like `acpi=off` and `i8042.reset` from forums. Some forum posts don't even have an answer.

It won't work. I've tried using an USB mouse and that hasn't even worked either. I might even try it again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyone there? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Check for  legacy support in BIOS ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/490736/295286)),  consider trying wireless keyboard/mouse, maybe bluetooth type.  According to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310324/297223)  Ubuntu doesn't fully support MacBook Pro from 2017, so you may have to manually install a few things. Can't help any further as I don't work with MacBooks.

Comment: Oh OK. Thank you very much. Mine is early 2016. I've tried Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Fedora and ElementaryOS. Still nothing. How come my keyboard works on GRUB though?

Comment: Also try  https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux#keyboard--touchpad  They've referenced a keyboard driver there, so might give this a try.

Comment: I'm not quite certain why this works in GRUB.  Possibly, GRUB just  gets a few parts working. While Ubuntu boots drivers ( aka modules ) should be loaded into kernel. If they're not loaded or there's no driver - hardware won't work.  But like I said, I don't have experience with MacBooks, nor GRUB that much to accurately answer why it works or doesn't

Comment: Thank you. It's interesting how I can do arrow keys in GRUB and stuff, but just not in Linux distros when they are booted.. Also, thank you for changing the tags!!

Comment: I strongly suggest you read the article linked from the post @SergiyKolodyazhnyy referenced. Summary: it's going to be a lot of work to get it to work at all, and even then some things are not going to act right.  Consider whether this is something you want to tackle, and if so, approach with patience and in a learning mode. https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7

Comment: OK. I will check that out. In fact, I already have and thank you.